# Is there efficient way to import Google sheet to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, google-sheets-api

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I've doing this project where I have to import my google sheet data with n columns into my mysql local database:

```
+-------+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| month | year |  Target  | product_id | Hq_id | Area_id | Region_id | Zone_id | Country_id |
+-------+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
|     6 | 2020 |   350.88 |          1 |   104 |      20 |         5 |       1 |          1 |
|     6 | 2020 | 14761.95 |          5 |   104 |      20 |         5 |       1 |          1 |
+-------+------+----------+------------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

The above data is my google sheet data. I've to insert this data into my localhost mysql table.
The table got columns

```
month, year, target, product_id, hq_headquarter_id, hq_area_id, hq_region_id, hq_zone_id, hq_country_id, month_year
```

I've used concat for generating month_year column as it is not in google sheet.

But in the google sheet I've 10k+ records to insert. I'm inserting the data cell by cell which is not that efficient way to do. And the google sheet has limit of 100 requests per run. I'm able to insert only 11 rows which is 99 cells ~= 100 requests.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import mysql.connector
import json 
import datetime

TABLE_COLUMNS = ['month', 'year', 'target', 'product_id', 'Hq id', 'Area_id', 'Region_id', 'Zone_id', 'Country_id']
INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO sap_targets (month, year, target, product_id, hq_headquarter_id, hq_area_id, hq_region_id, hq_zone_id, hq_country_id, month_year) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, concat(year, lpad(month, 2, '0')))"


AUTH_FILE = "googlespreadauthfile.json"
FILENAME = "TestFile"
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(AUTH_FILE,scopes)
googleClient = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sheet = googleClient.open(FILENAME)
sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(0)

connection = mysql.connector.connect( host= "localhost", user="root", password="", database="database" )

cursor = connection.cursor()

for r in range(2, len(sheet_instance.get_all_records())):
    month = sheet_instance.cell(r, 1).value
    year = sheet_instance.cell(r, 2).value
    target = sheet_instance.cell(r, 3).value
    product_id = sheet_instance.cell(r, 4).value
    hq_headquarter_id = sheet_instance.cell(r, 5).value
    hq_area_id = sheet_instance.cell(r,6).value
    hq_region_id = sheet_instance.cell(r, 7).value
    hq_zone_id = sheet_instance.cell(r, 8).value
    hq_country_id = sheet_instance.cell(r, 9).value

    values = (month, year, target, product_id, hq_headquarter_id, hq_area_id, hq_region_id, hq_zone_id, hq_country_id)

    cursor.execute(INSERT_QUERY, values)

cursor.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

As I've to increase my request capacity my G-Console, is there any way to insert 100 rows in 100 requests ( As I'm doing cell by cell ). Can we do it row by row to insert all the rows?

I really appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Export the worksheet to local CSV-file then import it to MySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: @Akina That is the other way. But I've to import directly from spreadsheet to my local dB. I appreciate your suggestion, but it changes the theme of the project.

Comment: If so then assign the whole data range to an array (or iterate row-by-row), then join each array's row into a string valid as INSERT VALUES statement data row, add INSERT INTO .. VALUES to the beginning, and execute the statement.

Comment: @Akina I tried that way too. Still I can insert only 100 rows per 100 requests. Is there any way that we can insert bulk in one single query? Might be a dumb question, but asking.

Comment: I would probably generate `insert` statements in a separate column (using worksheet string functions).  Then copy these into a UI for the database and run them.  Note:  It is trivial to connect Google Sheets to BigQuery tables so you might consider a BQ solution for your system.